# How to navigate and use NodeJS SDK documentation in GCP?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, sdk, documentation, google-api-nodejs-client

What is the best index to find and navigate through documentation about NodeJS SDK documentation in GCP?

For AWS its https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/index.html and its so easy to navigate around, but I dont find any similar in GCP.

I sometimes ends with some of these endpoints https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/, but there is no tree to navigate to other services.

Maybe this one? https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference

How do you usually do it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [Github page](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node)? It contains links to all relevant documentation, as well as sample code to help you get started.